# external hard drive (Old USB mass storage) wouldn't show up in media

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage, cypress

I have this 20 years old USB mass storage. It doesn't want to show up in the media neither in Ubuntu no in windows 10 when I plug it.

although ubunut is detetcting the hardware as lsusb: Bus 003 Device 005: ID 04b4:6830 Cypress Semiconductor Corp. CY7C68300A EZ-USB AT2 USB 2.0 to ATA/ATAPI

any one how to make this hard drive load? it seems like some sort of driver or compatibility.

[Cypress USB mass storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxQtz.jpg)

Comment: Probably it's not Plug and Play. Try the windows drivers [from here](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=Cypress+USB+drivers) and check out the drive's [manual](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/106381/CYPRESS/CY7C68300A.html)

Comment: As a last resort, you can always open the case, take out the drive and buy a new universal SATA enclosure. According to the manual, the drive is ATAPI, which can be read by any SATA interface.

Comment: "_It doesn't want to show up in the media_" ... do you mean it's not auto-mounting in `/media/`? What output does `dmesg` show when you plug it in?

Comment: @1NN Do you really think that the USB controller that is being detected is the problem? It's a lot more likely the actual drive being dead now...

Comment: Does the drive still spin up?  Take the cover off and find out if you can't tell with it on.